# Set fixed number of rows per page, PDF generation using itextsharp

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, pdf-generation, itext

I have a `List<object>` and this list contains thousands of record. I want to generated pdf using itextsharp. and `Pdfptable` to generated pdf it is working fine, but  but I want only 10 records per page in pdf.
How can I do it?

Comment: How about a loop which retrieves (up to) 10 items from that list, creates a table with these items, adds the table to the document, and proceeds to the next page? Or did I misinterpret your question?

Comment: yes. this works fine but I table covers only half of the pdf page other half one remains blank, i want that table 10 rows will cover up whole pdf page.. how it can be done..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way to set the number of rows per page:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

namespace RowsCountSample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4))
            {
                var pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, new FileStream("Test.pdf", FileMode.Create));
                pdfDoc.Open();

                var table1 = new PdfPTable(3);
                table1.HeaderRows = 2;
                table1.FooterRows = 1;

                //header row 
                var headerCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("header"));
                headerCell.Colspan = 3;
                headerCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                table1.AddCell(headerCell);

                //footer row 
                var footerCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("footer"));
                footerCell.Colspan = 3;
                footerCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                table1.AddCell(footerCell);

                //adding some rows 
                for (int i = 0; i < 70; i++)
                {
                    //adds a new row
                    table1.AddCell(new Phrase("Cell[0], Row[" + i + "]"));
                    table1.AddCell(new Phrase("Cell[1], Row[" + i + "]"));
                    table1.AddCell(new Phrase("Cell[2], Row[" + i + "]"));

                    //sets the number of rows per page
                    if (i > 0 && table1.Rows.Count % 7 == 0)
                    {
                        pdfDoc.Add(table1);
                        table1.DeleteBodyRows();
                        pdfDoc.NewPage();
                    }
                }

                pdfDoc.Add(table1);
            }

            //open the final file with adobe reader for instance. 
            Process.Start("Test.pdf");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the most recent version of iTextSharp (5.3.3), new functionality was added allowing you to define breakpoints: `SetBreakPoints(int[] breakPoints)`
If you define an array of multiples of 10, you can use this to get the desired effect.

If you have an older version, you should loop over the list and create a new PdfPTable for every 10 objects. Note that this is the better solution if you want to keep the memory use of your application low.

Comment: yes. 2nd option works fine for me... this works fine but I table covers only half of the pdf page other half one remains blank, i want that table 10 rows will cover up whole pdf page.. how it can be done..?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this. There's a method to extend the last row, but then you'll have a final row with plenty of blank space. There's also a method to set a fixed row height, but if there's more content than row height, the content that doesn't fit will be lost. Finally, there's a method to set a minimum height (you could use the page height / 10), but if there's more content the row will exceed the minimum height, and the table will be split and distributed over two page. The description of your needs is insuffient for people to be able to answer.